# Inequality constraints and the max function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $g_i(x):\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$, for $i=1,\ldots,n$, be continuous convex functions. Define $g_{\rm max}$ as $g_{\rm max}(x) \triangleq \mbox{max}_{i=1,\ldots,n}\{g_i(x)\}$. Define also the following feasible sets:
$$\mathcal{F}_1 \triangleq \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: g_i(x)\leq0 ~~\forall i \}$$
and
$$\mathcal{F}_2 \triangleq \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: g_{\rm max}(x)\leq0 \}$$

Which statements are true (if any)? Why?

1) $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_2$

2) $\mathcal{F}_1 \supseteq \mathcal{F}_2$

3) Statementes 1 and 2, i.e., $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{F}_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all statements are true as 
$$x^* \in \mathcal{F_2} \Rightarrow g_{max}(x^*) \leq 0 $$
but, $0 \geq g_{max}(x^*) \geq g_i(x^*)$ for all i. Then, $\mathcal{F}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_1$.

On the other hand, take $y  \in \mathcal{F}_1$, then $g_i(y) \leq 0$ for all $i$ and as $i = 1,...,n$ is finite then $g_{max}(y) = g_j(y)$ for some $j$, then $g_{max}(y) \leq 0$. Then, $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_2$.

Were we conclude that, 
$\mathcal{F}_2 = \mathcal{F}_1$.

Comment: You are correct. And the reason is very simple - the maximum among $m$ numbers is non-positive if and only if all of the numbers are non-positive. In your case, the numbers are $g_1(x), \dots, g_m(x)$.